# GPS coordinates to google map

Tags: android, gps

I'm working on an android application where I send latitude and longitude from my "A" activity to a "B" activity using bluetooth and in "B" activity I recieve them as simple texts, I want to convert them to a location on map. How can I do this?

Comment: Bluetooth to send lat lon to another activity??? Why not set data on Intents? Did you read about google maps?

Comment: I'm sorry I mean to send data from an application to another, like bluetooth chat between devices @user1930106

Answer (score -1):

You may try this ...

```
Location location = new Location(""); // provider name is unnecessary
location.setLatitude(0.0d); // your latitude
location.setLongitude(0.0d); // your longitude
```